# meta description greek letters

Tags: php, html, unicode, utf-8, meta

I have a problem with php news aggregator site.

When post meta description have greek letters i have this problem :

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Τυνησία: Ανοιξαν οι κάλπες για τις βουλευτικές εκλογές</title>
    **<meta name="description" content="&#902;&nu;&omicron;&iota;&xi;&alpha;&nu; &omicron;&iota; &kappa;&#940;&lambda;&pi;&epsilon;&sigmaf; &sigma;&tau;&eta;&nu; &Tau;&upsilon;&nu;&eta;&sigma;&#943;&alpha; &sigma;&#942;&mu;&epsilon;&rho;&alpha; &sigma;&tau;&iota;&sigmaf; 8 &#974;&rho;&alpha; &E">**
    <meta name="keywords" content="Τυνησία:,Ανοιξαν,οι,κάλπες,για,τις,βουλευτικές,εκλογές">
```

i haven't problem with title or keywords but only with description.

Comment: Please show the `php` code generating the description and maybe we can help.

Comment: Try removing encoding when displaying content for meta description.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem. That's a perfectly valid (though unnecessarily long) way of including greek letters in an HTML file. Any HTML parser will read it correctly, for example:

```
>>> $doc= DOMDocument::loadHTML($your_document_as_above);
>>> echo $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta')->item(4)->getAttribute('content');

Άνοιξαν οι κάλπες στην Τυνησία σήμερα στις 8 ώρα &E
```

It could be a problem if you were attempting to read HTML using regex, but I can't imagine anyone would do anything daft like that.